# Jenkins LDAP authentication does a unindexed search

Tags: jenkins, ldap

I'm installing a new Jenkins server (let's name it "A") and my LDAP authentication runs into the error

"[LDAP: error code 50 - You do not have sufficient privileges to perform an unindexed search"

The LDAP configration is identically to another Jenkins installation (version 1.642.2, let's name it "B") in the same network where LDAP works fine (Due to security reasons, I can't give exact names below)

```
 - Server: ldaps://server.domain:port
 - root DN: dc=XXX,dc=com
 - User search base: ou=people
 - User search filter: uid={0}
 - Manager DN: uid=XYZ,ou=people,dc=XXX,dc=com
 - Manager Password: ****

Group search base and Group search filte are not defined
```

The server "A" has currently no openldap2-client package installed. So I can't test on the command line on server "A".

When testing on server "B", the following query returns successfully:

`ldapsearch -x -D "uid=XYZ,ou=people,dc=XXX,dc=com" -W -H ldaps://server.domain:port 'uid=myAccount'`

Without giving the account to search for

`ldapsearch -x -D "uid=XYZ,ou=people,dc=XXX,dc=com" -W -H ldaps://server.domain:port`

returns the same error as I get in Jenkins on "A": "[LDAP: error code 50 - You do not have sufficient privileges to perform an unindexed search".
This works as expected, indeed.

So I assume, that somehow the User search filter `uid={0}` in Jenkins "A" isn't interpreted correctly.

I created a new log recorder in Jenkins for the "hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm" with priority "All", but it doesn't give more information about the LDAP query.

Any hints what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Group Search Base "ou=groups" did the trick!

This is not necessary in Jenkins Vers. 1.642.2 - the Jenkins Version, which is installed on my question's server "B". There everything works fine without this option.

When using the LTS Version 2.263.1 (I forgot to mention the version in my question) it's necessary (in my case) to add the Group Search Base.

Thanks to all the people, who spend some time for reading my post!

Regards!